# get all links from html even with show more link

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautifulsoup for html parsing.

I am using the following code :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = "http://www.wikipathways.org//index.php?query=signal+transduction+pathway&species=Homo+sapiens&title=Special%3ASearchPathways&doSearch=1&ids=&codes=&type=query"

main_url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = main_url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    print a[href]
```

but I am not getting output links like : 
    http://www.wikipathways.org/index.php/Pathway:WP26

and also imp thing is there are 107 pathways. but I will not get all the links as other lins depends on "show links" at the bottom of the page.

so, how can I get all the links (107 links) from that url?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is line 8, `content = url.read()`. You're not actually reading the webpage, you're actually just doing nothing (If anything, you should be getting an error).

`main_url` is what you want to read, so change line 8 to:

```
content = main_url.read()
```

You also have another error, `print a[href]`. `href` should be a string, so it should be:

```
print a['href']
```

Comment: ya thanks but can you tell me how can i retrieve all 107 urls?

Comment: Interesting, when parsing the page, I get `<div id="searchResults"></div>` but all of the 107 links should be in there, but they aren't.

Comment: @sam The content is loaded with JavaScript, so to get everything else BeautifulSoup might not be the module to use. Have a look at `Selenium` (link to docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ). I believe this module would be better for such events like this.

Comment: @sam Oh, I noticed below that you don't want to use Selenium. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `lxml` its faster and better for parsing html worth investing the time to learn it.

```
from lxml.html import parse
dom = parse('http://www.wikipathways.org//index.php?query=signal+transduction+pathway&species=Homo+sapiens&title=Special%3ASearchPathways&doSearch=1&ids=&codes=&type=query').getroot()
links = dom.cssselect('a')
```

That should get you going.

Comment: I would add those details to your question. If you need to use, show more that will likely require something like phantomjs or  selenium.

Comment: i dont want to use selenium as it needs server to be run. kindly let me know module which will be easy to handle in windows

Comment: yes i reached till u posted. it gives elements and i want to find the names from those elements. also can u let me know about getting all 107 pathway links?

Comment: lxml is great when a web page is XML compliant but many html pages are not. beautifulsoup is great at dealing with much html trickery.